# disable a transition when changing page

Tags: vue.js

With Vue.js, when I delete a reply, I use a "transition-group" to fadeout the reply.

However, if I'm changing the reply page, I also see the fadeout.

How can I disable the fadeout of replies when I change the replies page ?

```
<transition-group name="list" tag="div">
    <div v-for="(reply, index) in items" :key="reply.id">
        <reply :data="reply" @deleted="remove(index)"></reply>
    </div>
</transition-group>

<paginator :dataSet="dataSet" @updated="fetch"></paginator>
```

css :

```
.list-enter, .list-leave-to {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `changing the reply page` are you using [`vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make the `<transition-group>` `name="list"` a property that reacts to `data` with `:name="animToUse"`
2. Put `animToUse` as a property on `data`
3. Change `animToUse` to a non transition whenever you don't want the transition

---

If you are using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) see it's docs about transitions: [Route-Based Dynamic Transition](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#route-based-dynamic-transition)

Comment: `remove(index) {
            this.animToUse = 'list';
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }`   - With this, I only see the animation when I delete the reply.  But after that, changing page transition stil occurs.      It doesn't work if I call `this.animToUse = 'list';`  again after `splice` . Why ?

Comment: I can put `this.animToUse = '';`  elsewhere (before fetching next page) and it works.   Thanks!    I guess I cannot call this.animToUSe before and after the splice, because it's asynchronous.

Comment: It still keep old items for a while until new one appear, but just without animation.